# Why is this image not becoming darker?

Tags: html, css

Can someone point out why my image is not becoming darker? I am teaching myself some HTML and CSS and cant get this image to become darker.

```css
.carousel-content {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.image1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-content">
  <img class="image1" src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: none of your css will make it darker.

Comment: You are actually working on the background of the image.

Comment: Look into [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp) for messing with image. If you want to use background-color to tint it position the element with the bgcolor above the image either by using [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) or having the bgcolor element follow the image element in the dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background is behind the image,if you want to make it darker you need to put an overlay top of it, and set transparent background there.

```css
.carousel-content {
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 275px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border-right: 2px dashed #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-content">
  <img class="image1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150/ff0000/ffffff" />
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Or you can use css filter in modern browsers:

```css
img {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also keep it the way you have it (assuming a black background) and just set the opacity for the image to fade it a bit and show the solid background color.

```css
.carousel-content {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.image1 {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-content">
  <img class="image1" src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg" />
</div>
```